# Is it possible to cancel a blocking call in C++ 11 or 14?

Tags: c++11, c++14, stdthread, stdasync

My gcc compiler supports C++ 14.

**Scenario:**
I want to know if there is a way I can force cancel out of a blocking call and stop my `std::thread` safely.

**Code:**

```
// Member vars declared in MyClass.hpp
std::atomic<bool> m_continue_polling = false;
std::thread       m_thread;

StartThread() {
    m_continue_polling = true;
    m_thread = std::thread { [this] {
        while (m_continue_polling) {
           int somevalue = ReadValue(); // This is a blocking call and can take minutes
        }
    }};
}

StopThread() {

    m_continue_polling = false;
    try {
        if (m_thread.joinable()) {
            m_thread.join();
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception & /*e*/) {
        // Log it out
    }
}
```

In above code `ReadValue` is a blocking call which goes into a library and reads on a fd which some device driver related code which I have no control on.

**Question:**
I need `StopThread` to be able to stop the thread and cancel the call that is blocking on `ReadValue`. *How can I do this?* Is there some way in C++11 or 14?

**PS:**
Probably `std::async` could be a solution? But I wish to know if there are better ways. If `std::async` is the best approach then how to effectively use it this scenario without causing bad side effects.

Comment: C++ sadly doesn't have support for non-cooperative way of terminating a single thread

Comment: If it can take minutes, I would consider to export the blocking functionality (int ReadValue()) to a second small executable, that is possible to terminate, and execute it from the code asyncronically, waiting for the result during sampling m_continue_polling in intervals (or with a combination of conditional variable if you don't like the idea of polling).

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you can get the native thread handle and use [`pthread_cancel`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) function. Provided the thread did not disable cancelability and that the thread is blocked in a cancellation point. You will have to read the documentation carefully to understand all the caveats.

Comment: But is that actually "safe" though? What happens if the thread has locked a mutex? What happens to the destructor calls to all stack object in that thread?

Comment: @NicolBolas You will have to read the documentation carefully, which I am not going to cite here. `glibc` throws an exception, so your mutex is going to be unlocked if a scoped lock is used.

Comment: ok. as I expected. there are potential ways but with possible side effects